# Flexible font size JavaFX

Tags: javafx, fonts, size

I'm trying to make a flexible GUI. I want my interface not to change its proportions when its size changes. I did this by using a GridPane, but I have some problems with font size of TextField, Button. I can't make it flexible, can you tell me? As a sample

```
TextField textField = new TextField ();
HBox hb = new HBox();
hb.getChildren().addAll(textField);
aStage.setScene(new Scene(hb));
```

Comment: What do you mean your having trouble with font size are you talking about labels or font on buttons or checkboxes this is very ambiguous you need to give more information about what your problem is and maybe even provide a code sample so people can test out what your issue is

Comment: @Matt every node containing a text has the problem. Default font size is 12px. If you try change size of stage font size not to change

Comment: Yes font size doesn't change on its own you will need to modify it yourself pick your node and do `.setFont(Font.font(16));`
you can also create one font for all of them by doing  `Font fontSize  = Font.font(16);` and `.setFont(fontSize);`

Comment: @Matt i know it, but i need to change font size when size of its node changes

Comment: Have you looked at `ScalableContentPane` from JFXtras?

Comment: @hudsonb hmm, may be it is what i need. If i cnhange size of ScalableContentPane then all its children change size, right?

Comment: Yes they all SCALE to fit the pane.

Comment: @hudsonb cool, tnx very much!